# Is there a place to discuss "recreational" development?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I just learned that [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is a thing, with it's own forum and everything.  Got me wondering:

Are there any forums or groups where the topic is **"recreational" coding/development/etc**?  ...as in, (likely unpaid) coding just for the sake of the puzzles, or learning, collaborating, helping others, etc.

Yeah, I'm a geek.   8)

---

***Edit:***

I suppose I have my answer!  I've seen evidence of Stack Overflow members sometimes taking things a little *too* seriously (in my opinion), and even belittling OP's who haven't done enough research before posting a question -- but *I do acknowledge* that it ultimately leads to a golden source of quality information, free of pointless spam or questions that have been answered numerous times.

So this isn't the place for "recreation".  Gotcha.

One example of what I'm looking for is the 'nonprofit collaboratione' piece.  I'm building a web tool, ad free, intended to be a resource to make life easier for a certain segment of developers.  I posess the background skill on the topic, however I'm just not learning web design as quickly as I would like (I'm not 20 anymore!), in order to complete this project in a reasonable timeframe/quality level...  whereas it's probably a matter of an hour or two of the right person's time (and I would *absolutely* be learning in the process, and credit would be gleefully shared).

Another, related example is related to graphic design:  I am not very artistic so I've done a ton of research into possible visual layouts for this site, and I have a half a dozen idea I'm considering.  Sadly I don't have anyone 'IRL' to give me feedback on my potential designs, plus I'd rather focus on coding as opposed to art.

Honestly I'm afraid to even clarify these things, for fear of being shunned for "seeking free labour" or such!  In trying to seek alternative sources of information, I posted a link to a survey a couple weeks ago, basically asking for input on what people would like to see in a site like that.  My post on Stack Overflow was deleted within a record 18 seconds.  Impressive!

Comment: [codegolf.se] "[is a question and answer site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour)" and not a forum.

Comment: Discuss the concept of "recreational" coding, or _doing_ recreational coding? The last is already answered in your own question: CodeGolf.SE . Its full name is _Programming Puzzles and Code Golf_; programming puzzles other than golf are welcome there.

Comment: Can it give 2-3 examples of the kinds of questions you'd ideally like to be able to ask on this recreational topic?

Comment: The intended audience of your coding doesn't matter on Stack Overflow, as long as the question fits the guidelines otherwise. For example, I'm reasonably confident that the people asking [\[brainfuck\] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck) are not working on code that's paying their bills.

Answer (score 3):

It would depend on what you mean by recreational. For me (and I suspect many others), recreational would imply topics that aren't ordinarily encountered during a day job (and / or) asking or answering questions about them that aren't tied to a paying job. Not everyone is good at golf :)

What we don't support on Stack Overflow, Code Golf or [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) is mindless fun, questions need to help you actually get better at doing something. That might be an exercise in flexing your Python chops to get a working example in less than 80 characters posted, or just exploring design patterns you're not likely to encounter professionally.

So there really is a difference between knowledge with no immediate practical value for the asker and just having some fun, even though the two are likely to intersect. However, we *do* ask that the majority of your questions focus on real world problems that you face, because that's how we build a solid library of knowledge for future visitors.

Hence, if you just want the satisfaction of accomplishing something clever, Code Golf is probably the closest we come to 'fun' that you'll find. If you just enjoy learning, even if there's no immediate goal or need, then any of our programming sites are probably well suited, as long as you put some effort into your questions and they're likely to be useful to future visitors.